# How do I get a list of checkbox values to post to my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view with a list of checkboxes.  It display fine, but on Post, the count=0 for my list.  I've seen a bunch of post on SO that all say the same thing, which I've trie, but it's not working, so I must be missing something.

My ViewModels:

```
public class ParentViewModel 
{
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        ClassOfTradeList = new List<CheckBoxListItem>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CheckBoxListItem> ClassOfTradeList { get; set; }
}

public class CheckBoxListItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Then my View:

```
@model app.Models.ViewModels.ParentViewModel

// other parent fields

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ClassOfTradeList.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ClassOfTradeList[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClassOfTradeList[i].Id)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClassOfTradeList[i].IsSelected, Model.ClassOfTradeList[i].Name)
    <br />
}
```

My Post in the controller:

```
public ActionResult ParentReturn(ParentViewModel model)
{

}
```

My Get:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Parent()
{
    var model = new ParentViewModel();
    //fill in properties here
    model.ClassOfTradeList = ClassOfTradeList();
    return View(model);
}

private List<CheckBoxListItem> ClassOfTradeList()
    {
        var classofTrades = _tradeRepo.GetAll().Where(c => c.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
        var classOfTradeList = new List<CheckBoxListItem>();
        classOfTradeList = classofTrades.Select(c => new CheckBoxListItem
        {
            Name = c.Name,
            Id = c.Id
        }).ToList();

        return classOfTradeList;
    }
```

So when I get back to the controller, the model.ClassOfTrades.Count =0.  What am I missing?

Comment: I've just replicated your setup with some assumptions and it has worked fine.  So in order to provide more help I'm going to need more information.  You've included your ParentReturn post method please add the get method as well.

Comment: It might be that the ids haven't populated correctly in the hidden fields.  One way of checking this would be using inspect element.

Comment: @DaveBarnett Ok, I added my get code above.  I checked and the ids are populating on the model in the get.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  When I first was trying to fix this, I put:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClassOfTradeList)
```

in the beginning of the View.  It was overriding my hiddenfor of the id later on in the view.

Thanks all for your help.  So removing that and keeping the code I have posted made it work.

Answer (score -2):

You should probably use "Model.ClassOfTradeList[i].Name" instead of Id.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ParentReturn", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.ClassOfTradeList.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.ClassOfTradeList[i].IsSelected);
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ClassOfTradeList[i].Name);
        @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.ClassOfTradeList[i].IsSelected, Model.ClassOfTradeList[i].Name);
        <br />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="click" />
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/C0trTW